# How to print multiple list items in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I'm looking for a way I can print multiple sharepoint list items from SharePoint Online.

At the moment im using the snipping tool and pasting the screenshot into word, and then printing the document.

I was just wondering if theres a better method? Is there a way to develop a fucntioning print button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could export lists to Excel then print the list items.

To export to Excel from SharePoint, you could refer to this article:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-to-excel-from-sharepoint-bfb2ea48-6118-4fa9-abb6-cced9424e5d9

Comment: Thanks, this will work as a workaround for now i believe.